# Letter to different recipients and addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that writes the same letter to each recipient and each address, but each letter will have the different names and address.

This is what i have so far.

```
def main():
    recipients = [] #should be names
    adresses = [] #letters and numbers

    filename = input("Please enter the name of the template file: ")
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    recipients = input("Please enter names of recipients: ")
    adresses = input("Please list addresses: ")

    for names in recipients:
        letter = "New York, New York\n17 November 2013\n \n", recipients[names], "\n" ,adresses, "\n\nDear",recipients[names],"\n\n" \
        "Thank you for your service to New York City, and\nin particular, to the education of its residents.\nThose in", adresses, "appreciate it!"\
        "\n\nBest wishes to", recipients[names], "and your family,\n\n"

        file.write(str(letter))

    file.close()
main()
```

When it writes out to the file it just writes one letter and just puts everything together.

What i want to be done is for a letter to DIFFERENT people and Different addresses in the SAME file.

Ex. This will all be in the SAME file.

```
   New York, New York
   11 March 2013

   person1
   Bronx NY

   Dear person1,

   Thank you for your service to New York City, and,
   in particular, to the education of its residents.
   Those in Bronx NY appreciate it!

   Best wishes to person1 and your family   


   New York, New York
   11 March 2013

   Person2
   New York NY

   Dear person2,

   Thank you for your service to New York City, and,
   in particular, to the education of its residents.
   Those in New York NY appreciate it!

   Best wishes to person2 and your family
```

Any help?

Using Python 3.x

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside from whatever your main problem is, your `letter` object is going to be a tuple of 11 strings, which means `str(letter)` is going to show up with 11 quoted and escaped strings with commas between them and parentheses around the whole thing. You need to look at [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), or other ways of building up strings.

Comment: While you're at it, look at the explanation of triple-quoted strings in the tutorial's [Strings](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) section.

Comment: it's not clear the problem you are trying to solve, try explaining exactly the output you want and what you currently have

Comment: @CameronSparr Edited to make this more clear

Comment: The problem is that `recipients` and `addresses` should be lists of names and addresses. At the moment they are just strings, so the `for` loop won't work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

First off, you're requesting a list of names and addresses, but you only get a single string from `input`. If you expect your user to specify several values, you'll need to parse that input string somehow to split up the values. For instance, you could split on commas:

```
recipients_str = input("Please enter names of recipients: ")
recipients = recipients_str.split(",")
```

The next issue you have is that your loop doesn't do what you appear to expect. In Python, a `for` loop gives you the values from the sequence you're looping on, not indexes. So, try:

```
for name in recipients:
```

Or, since you also have a list of addresses which should correspond to the list of names, use `zip` and get both name and address together:

```
for name, address in zip(recipients, addresses):
```

Next, you have issues with the code to create your letter string. You're currently making a tuple of strings, not a single one. A much better approach would be to use `str.format` to handle inserting the various values into the template:

```
letter_template = """New York, New York
11 March 2013
{name}
{address}

Dear {name},

Thank you for your service to New York City, and,
in particular, to the education of its residents.
Those in {address} appreciate it!

Best wishes to {name} and your family
"""

letter = letter_template.format(name=name, address=address)
```

Comment: With this comment you actually taught me alot, i didnt know i could do some of those things. I am currently working to see if i figure this out with what you showed me

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to a separate file for each recipient, rather than writing to the same file as you are currently doing:

```
def main():
    recipients = [] #should be names
    adresses = [] #letters and numbers

    recipients = input("Please enter names of recipients: ")
    adresses = input("Please list addresses: ")

    for names in recipients:
        letter = "CONTENTS OF LETTER"

        filename = input("Please enter the name of the template file: ")
        file = open(filename, 'w')
        file.write(str(letter))
        file.close()

main()
```

Be mindful that you'll be prompted for a new template file name for each iteration of the loop. You'll also need to ensure that each template name is unique so that prior files are not overwritten.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your question may not be asking what you're meaning to ask. Care to rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you need to write a unique file for each letter, the section of code below should be modified to create a file for each letter, you could do something like creating a counter and appending it to the filename to keep them unique.

```
    for names in recipients:
        letter = "New York, New York\n17 November 2013\n \n", recipients[names], "\n" ,adresses, "\n\nDear",recipients[names],"\n\n" \
        "Thank you for your service to New York City, and\nin particular, to the education of its residents.\nThose in", adresses, "appreciate it!"\
        "\n\nBest wishes to", recipients[names], "and your family,\n\n"

        file.write(str(letter))

    file.close()
```